# Styling nested navigators on Android with React Navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've prepared this small demo: https://snack.expo.io/B1kOKaJSZ

If you turn on Preview down there and use iOS, everything works as expected. That means navigating to nested scenes shows green background.

[image]

Now if you switch to Android, the nested scenes are just white and not even aligned, like the style is ignored.

[image]
[image]

I am still pretty much rookie to RN so there is probably some gotcha, but I am currently clueless.

I've tried this on a real device also and behavior is the same.

Update: Cleaned up the demo little bit: https://snack.expo.io/Byo0_feH-

Edit: I've filed the issue with React-Navigation: https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/2106

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting green screen neither on preview iOS nor on my personal iOS device.

Comment: Hmm, that's really strange. Obviously, I haven't made up those screenshots, so now I am even more clueless. Am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: it might be the "alignItems: center" line. It can cuz white screen if you use React-Navigation (at least on iOS).

Comment: Already tried that, except changing align it does help to solve an issue.